# Issue with cPanel installation

Tags: linux, centos, cloud, cpanel, whm

I am setting up cPanel on CentOS but have been facing this problem with connection. Its giving an error of *"Connection refused"*.

I am working on a system with proxy internet.

```
curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:41 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed connect to securedownloads.cpanel.net:443; Connection refused
```

Update:
I have changed my VM adapter setting to "Bridged" from "NAT"
Still facing the error.

```
curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest &amp;&amp; sh latest
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:33 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed connect to securedownloads.cpanel.net:443; Operation now in progress
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any firewall on your server which is blocking connections. Do a ping to securedownloads.cpanel.net.

```
ping securedownloads.cpanel.net
```

If ping is working and still your are getting this error.You can use wget as well.

```
wget https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

If you do not have wget. Install it.

```
yum install wget -y
```

Comment: Its still not working. I've checked the ping and that seems to be working fine. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Are you able to reach port 80? Just edit the URL to http and try. 
wget http://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest

Comment: It again didn't work. And btw how do I ping to specific port(80)?

Comment: You cannot ping to a port. You can only telnet to port 80. Whats the exact error message which you get when you give the wget command which I provided in the above comment.